# Division in Java equaling 0 when it shouldn't be

Tags: java

///     System.out.println("[Scrappy's Bucket List Rewards}");

```
    System.out.print("How many events have you attended?");

    int events;
    events = sc.nextInt();

    int percentEvents = events/63 * 100;

    if(events<7)
    {
        System.out.print("Check out events at 
    } else if (events < 16)
    {
        System.out.println("You've been to " + percentEvents + "% of all SBL events!");
        System.out.println("You've earned a Drawstring bag!");
        System.out.print(percentEvents);
    }
```

///
When I run this code and try to print the percentEvents the value turns out to be 0.What am I missing?

Comment: You're doing integer division. Change it to `double percentEvents = events / 63.0 * 100;`.

Comment: Or if you want an `int`, do the multiplication before the division.